# HDMI macbook air 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I'm having issues with my macbook air 2011 HDMI connection.  I am connecting through thunderbolt. Here is the problem; sometimes my mac connects to HDMI. Most of the time, it does not.  Once it is connected, it will work flawlessly as long as I leave it connected. Once I disconnect it, odds are it will not work again for a while, no matter how many times I reset/shutdown the computer, with power cable or without.  However, every once in a while, it does reconnect, and I haven't figured out why or how.  The only maybe hint I have is that when I connect it to another monitor, it might or might not work, but if it does work, it might then work on another monitor. Also, if I plug in another macbook, it might sometimes facilitate connection when I plug my macbook in afterwards.  Another hint is that at the apple store, on a same monitor, my HDMI would not connect, but after booting through their in-store LAN OS, it would work flawlessly. Most likely a driver-related issue, but have not figured out how to fix this. FWIW here is my display info :

13.3-inch (1440 x 900)
Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB

I can so far guarantee that these things are not the issue:

1. Monitor - I'm experiencing the same issue on multiple monitors
2. Cables - I've replaced cables and tested them with other macbooks while trouble shooting - they still work.
3. OS - I've formatted my entire OS. Even went to the apple store to have the mini apple partition wiped and reinstalled. That did not fix the issue. (Although wiping the mini partition did allow me to directly connect to HDMI a first time, so it helped reset something).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are actually connecting from mDP (mini Display Port) to HDMI, not Thunderbolt.  Which cable specifically are you using?  Which monitor are you using.  In my experience, HDMI has always been flaky.  It works great when the monitor is already on and active, but fails when the MBA goes to sleep.  Do you have the option to use DVI or DP?

Comment: @Allan is basically onto something here. Since your Mac doesn't actually have a HDMI port, you must be using some sort of cable to _convert_ from the Thunderbolt digital video output to HDMI. So, to help troubleshoot this it'd be really helpful to know what cable you're actually using and what monitor you have? Also, what version of MacOS are you running?

Comment: I am using a cable I bought off amazon, this one : https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B007RQ3J7G/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The monitor is a samsung S24C350L and I'm currently running El Capitan 10.11.16

Might I add that this problem also occurs using VGA connectors and accross different monitors. Also, after successfully connecting through HDMI to my samsung monitor, I could no longer connect through HDMI to my ASUS monitor. Connecting to my Samsung monitor once more worked. Not sure what to make of it